# cant find code which changes Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, orientation

I'm working on my app since a few weeks. Now i pointed out the bug, that if i rotate my Device, it always replaces my Fragment to the "Home-Fragment".. and i dont know why. I Was searching it with "find in path"-function in Android Studio. I searched for keywords like:

-orientation

-setOrientation

-Landscape

-Portrait

But didnt find the code-snippet which changes my Fragment on rotation...
Any tipps? How can i find out where the "fragment replace" gets called?

Comment: Can you put up some code so we can see please :)? When you rotate the device the activity gets destroyed and created again due to its life cycle methods. Do you want it to have both a portrait and landscape layout?

Comment: When you rotate the device the activity is launched again. So first fragment in your activity will be reloaded again i.e HomeFragment.

Comment: Tip : Please upload the relevant code with error (if any) in question.

Comment: What code should i put? its over 20 classes. 
I have a fragmentstatehandler, which replaces fragments.  If i want to place a new one, i call:

`fragmentStateHandler.replaceFrag(<enum of frag>, <optional Bundle with args>);`

arjun: what relevant code? i have no errors.


@activesince93 thanks.. this helps me a bit.. im working on it.

Answer (score 4):

the correct code to initialise the "home fragment" is like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new HomeFragment())
                .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

note that you only do the fragment transaction if `savedInstanceState == null`, if it's not null, the Android and Fragment frameworks will automatically recreate everything.

I'm pretty sure the reason that you're always replacing with the `homeFragment` is because you're not checking `savedInstanceState == null`

Comment: thanks. this helps me a lot.
Maybe it's that reason! im trying it out right now.

Answer (score -2):

Add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to the manifest in your activity. This will prevent your activity to recreate view after orientation changes.